# Many to one thread model

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I have read about many to one thread model, but i have a doubt that are those many users threads belongs to one process or may belong to different processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many to one thread model, many user threads from one process are mapped to a single kernel thread.

Comment: So if i have 10 processes each having 3 threads, then kernel threads will be 10 in many to one model( provided OS can have 10 kernel threads at a time). Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: OP - while @Stephane's answer is correct, beware.  If this is for research/assignment/homework, fine.  If you are thinking of implementing something like this, best not.

Comment: yeah this is just for some kind of reasearch, nothing else.... i know none of the modern OS use this..